# Python: Eval dictionary value from matched string key (discord.py)

Tags: python, dictionary, discord.py

So I'm writing a discord bot with discord.py, and I'm wishing to call a function based on user input. I need to take the user's input, match it to a dictionary key, and have the value call the function.

Such as:
User sends message like "!b command arg"
If Command matches a dictionary key, execute value like "command"="function()"

What I have now is

```
cmds = open('commands.txt', 'rU') 
for line in cmds:
    if firstCommand == line:
        "something to pull relevant dict value"
        exec(something)
```

I know absolutely that this won't work. But I'm stuck on how to make it work. I hope I've made enough sense such that I can get some help on this, cause I'm stuck but definitely feel like this should be possible.
*For the record, `firstCommand` already has `!b`  removed, as well as all text after the first command (args). `splitCommand` has all the args as a list after [0].*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be using [`Cogs`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs) here, but what you are trying to do is entirely possible. Here's how :

I have a test file with the following functions :

```py
def foo():
    print("This is working!")
```

Doing this will let me call the function outside the main file :

```py
@bot.command()
async def func(ctx, funcname, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(__import__("test"), funcname):
        await ctx.send("Function not found!")
        return
    getattr(__import__("test"), funcname)(*args, **kwargs)
```

(replace `test` with your module name)

This will result in the following :
[image: discord message]
[image: stdout]

You can do a lot more cooler things if you can pass in `context` and the function accepts it.

Here's what I mean :
**test.py** :

```py
def foo(_):
    # We'll use an throwaway variable name because we don't need ctx here
    print("This is working!")


async def bar(ctx):
    # To demonstrate a function that also takes a positional argument
    await ctx.send(f"This is working!, hello there {ctx.author.name}")
```

**main.py** :

```py
@bot.command()
async def func(ctx, funcname, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(__import__("test"), funcname):
        await ctx.send("Function not found!")
        return
    function = getattr(__import__("test"), funcname)
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(function):
        await function(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
        return
    function(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
    # Do notice how I passed in the context there
    # and how coro functions are accomoated for.
```

Result :
[image: final result]

Full code of `main.py` :

```py
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def func(ctx, funcname, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(__import__("test"), funcname):
        await ctx.send("Function not found!")
        return
    function = getattr(__import__("test"), funcname)
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(function):
        await function(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
        return
    function(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
    # Do notice how I passed in the context there
    # and how coro functions are accomoated for.


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```